# nltk - corpus of gzipped files

Tags: python, nltk

Given a folder with gzipped files i want to create a corpora:

The following fails

```
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
wordlists = PlaintextCorpusReader('.', '.*')
wordlists.words('a.txt.gz')
```

The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/collections.py", line 225, in __repr__
    for elt in self:
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/util.py", line 296, in iterate_from
    tokens = self.read_block(self._stream)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/plaintext.py", line 122, in _read_word_block
    words.extend(self._word_tokenizer.tokenize(stream.readline()))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 1142, in readline
    new_chars = self._read(readsize)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 1374, in _read
    chars, bytes_decoded = self._incr_decode(bytes)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 1405, in _incr_decode
    return self.decode(bytes, 'strict')
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

What is the correct way to do this?

I am using python 3.6 with nltk 3.2.2

Comment: Is unzipping the files an option? That would make life a lot easier.

Comment: No. I want to have them in gzipped format to save space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nltk's readers can handle a corpus stored as a zipped archive of files. You have a regular directory full of gzipped files, which the nltk doesn't appear to handle out of the box; anyway one large archive is usually more compact than several small ones, so you can solve your problem by switching to a single compressed archive.

I was able to get the nltk to read a zipped (not gzipped) archive that looks like this:

```
    % unzip -l big-corpus.zip
    Archive:  big-corpus.zip
      Length     Date   Time    Name
     --------    ----   ----    ----
            0  05-08-14 00:34   big-corpus/
         5258  05-08-14 00:34   big-corpus/austen-emma.txt
         5391  05-08-14 00:34   big-corpus/austen-persuasion.txt
         ...
```

I.e., the corpus files should be in a subdirectory. For some reason, I couldn't get the reader to accept an archive that contains the files at the top level (without a subdirectory). One way to get this structure is if you have a folder `big-corpus` containing your corpus, and you execute the following command in the directory containing `big-corpus`:

```
% zip -r big-corpus.zip big-corpus
```

Once you have this, just use the following syntax to initialize a reader:

```
corpus = PlaintextCorpusReader("big-corpus.zip/big-corpus/", r".*\.txt")
```